# How to handle simultaneous data request and response in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database

The problem scenario is:

I have a database table 'User_Datails_Table' with fileds(id,username, luckyNumber).
All logged in users can updated their 'luckyNumber' as they wish. Also a user has option to view all the existing user details. There is an option to sort(DESC) the user details based on 'luckyNumbers'.

The requirement is such that I need to query the database with LIMIT values. For example,query fetching 1st two records(LIMIT 0,2), then next query fetching next 2 records(LIMIT 2,2) so on.

Consider the database contains 4 record:

```
id  username   luckyNumber
1   USER1       67
2   USER2       66
3   USER3       64
4   USER4       63
```

Two user(USER1 and USER3) are logged in.

If USER3 fetches the first two records using LIMIT 0,2( result is USER1 and  USER2) and USER1 changes his luckyNumber to 62(simultaneously).

Now if USER3 fetches the next two records using LIMIT 2,2( result is USER4 and  USER1). So USER1 gets repeated in the result.

I use php to fetch the mysql database. How can such a scenario be handled? Does mysql handle this automatically?

Comment: How many rows maximum can the user fetch using this method?  How are the requests for the next two rows made?

Comment: It is a get request. The request is from device.A user is the one who is using the device. Hence the device cannot fetch all records and do pagination. It has to fetch few records at a time.

Comment: Do you want the list to display in the exact order that it was at the time the user requested the first page (like a snapshot), or just that the same user should not show up multiple times as they are viewing the pages?

Comment: I want the same snapshot.For example, the pagination that happens in mobile apps where "load more" is shown but the old data is retained